# How to build spark application using Scala IDE and Maven?

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, mahout

I'm new to Scala, Spark and Maven and would like to build spark application described [here](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/examples/bin/spark-document-classifier.mscala). It uses the Mahout library.

I have Scala IDE install and would like to use Maven to build the dependencies (which are the Mahout library as well as Spark lib). I couldn't find a good tutorial to start. Could someone help me figure it out?

Answer (score 3):

First try compiling simple application with Maven in Scala IDE. The key of Maven project is directory structure and pom.xml. Although I don't use Scala IDE, this document seems helpful.
http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/m2eclipse/

Next step is to add dependency on Spark in pom.xml you can follow this document.
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/04/how-to-run-a-simple-apache-spark-app-in-cdh-5/

For latest version of Spark and Mahout artifacts you can check them here:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.mahout

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need following tools to get started ( based on recent availability) -

- Scala IDE for Eclipse – Download latest version of Scala IDE from
  [here](http://scala-ide.org/).
- Scala Version – 2.11 ( make sure scala compiler is set to
  this version as well)
- Spark Version 2.2 ( provided in maven
  dependency)
- winutils.exe

> For running in Windows environment , you need hadoop binaries in
>   windows format. winutils provides that and we need to set
>   hadoop.home.dir system property to bin path inside which winutils.exe
>   is present. You can download winutils.exe [here](http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/hdp-win-alpha/winutils.exe) and place at path
>   like this – c:/hadoop/bin/winutils.exe

And, you can define Spark Core Dependency in your Maven POM.XML for your project, to get started with.

```
   <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
     <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.0</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
```

And in your Java/Scala class define this property, to run on your local environmet on Windows -

```
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "c://hadoop//");
```

More details and full setup details can be found [here](https://saurzcode.in/2017/10/configure-spark-application-eclipse/).